# What is the Salah of Imam Hussain (a.s.)?

Tags: salat, source-identification, shiism, hussain

I've heard that there is a Salah as the Salah of Imam Hussain (peace be upon him)
But I don’t know how its circumstance is. Does anyone know how it is?

(notice: It doesn't mean that it is said prayer for Imam Hussain (a.s.) instead of Allah, haply it is famous as this name. (As e.g. many streets or other things are called by the names of good persons. Or for instance if the name of a gate of Masjid-al-Nabi is called Baab-Al-Jabraeel, then it doesn't mean that it is his gate, haply this gate has been named and is famous by the respect of him... / Or AFAIK, e.g. there is a Salah (prayer) which is known as Salah Jafar-Al-Tayyar, so, it doesn't mean we prayer/worshiping him, haply, ... / And  so forth.)

Note: I am looking for an authentic tradition that narrated it.

(**Shia View**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Salah (as a prayer which is famous as Imam Hussain (a.s.)) (which is prayed for Allah) has quoted from Seyyed ibn Tavoos that is considered as a Mustahab practice (Salah) to be offered on Friday, (likewise by some differences at the last part of a dua which is after that) in the half (middle) of Sha’ban month beside the shrine of Imam Hussain (peace be upon him).

This Salah is consisted of 2 salahs (which each one is consisted of 2 rek’ats as well, actually totally 4 rek’ahs)). It shall be offered Surahs Hamd(al-Fatiha) and Tawhid(al-Ekhlas) 50 times (each one 50 times), and after the Zikr of Ruku’ (at ruku’ position) it shall be offered both Surahs Hamd and Tawhid (each one 10 times). Afterwards, both of those Surahs should be offered when you come back from the Ruku’ position. And at the first Sajdah and between 2 Sojud (when sitting) and at the second Sajdah = 10 times (each of Hamd and Tawhid Surahs). Then recite the following dua at the end of fourth rek’ah:

> «اللَّهُمَّ أَنْتَ الَّذی اسْتَجَبْتَ لِآدَمَ و حَوَّاءَ إِذْ قالا
>   رَبَّنا ظَلَمْنا أَنْفُسَنا وَ إِنْ لَمْ تَغْفِرْ لَنا وَ تَرْحَمْنا
>   لَنَکُونَنَّ مِنَ الْخاسِرِینَ، وَ نَادَاکَ نُوحٌ فَاسْتَجَبْتَ لَهُ
>   وَ نَجَّیْتَهُ وَ أَهْلَهُ مِنَ الْکَرْبِ الْعَظِیمِ، وَ أَطْفَأْتَ
>   نَارَ نُمْرُودَ عَنْ خَلِیلِکَ إِبْرَاهِیمَ فَجَعَلْتَهَا بَرْداً وَ
>   سَلاماً، وَ أَنْتَ الَّذِی اسْتَجَبْتَ لِأَیُّوبَ إِذْ نَادَى
>   مَسَّنِیَ الضُّرُّ وَ أَنْتَ أَرْحَمُ الرَّاحِمِینَ فَکَشَفْتَ ما بِهِ
>   مِنْ ضُرٍّ وَ آتَیْتَهُ أَهْلَهُ وَ مِثْلَهُمْ مَعَهُمْ رَحْمَةً مِنْ
>   عِنْدِکَ وَ ذِکْرى‏ لِأُولِی الْأَلْبابِ، وَ أَنْتَ الَّذِی
>   اسْتَجَبْتَ لِذِی النُّونِ حِینَ نَادَاکَ مِنَ الظُّلُماتِ أَنْ لا
>   إِلهَ إِلَّا أَنْتَ سُبْحانَکَ إِنِّی کُنْتُ مِنَ الظَّالِمِینَ
>   فَنَجَّیْتَهُ مِنَ الْغَمِّ، وَ أَنْتَ الَّذِی اسْتَجَبْتَ لِمُوسَى‏
>   وَ هَارُونَ دَعْوَتَهُمَا حِینَ قُلْتَ قَدْ أُجِیبَتْ دَعْوَتُکُما
>   فَاسْتَقِیما وَ غَرَّقْتَ فِرْعَوْنَ وَ قَوْمَهُ، وَ غَفَرْتَ
>   لِدَاوُدَ ذَنْبَهُ وَ تُبْتَ عَلَیْهِ رَحْمَةً مِنْکَ وَ ذِکْرَى، وَ
>   فَدَیْتَ إِسْمَاعِیلَ بِذِبْحٍ عَظِیمٍ بَعْدَ مَا أَسْلَمَ وَ تَلَّهُ
>   لِلْجَبِینِ فَنَادَیْتَهُ بِالْفَرَجِ وَ الرَّوْحِ، وَ أَنْتَ الَّذِی
>   نَادَاکَ زَکَرِیَّا نِداءً خَفِیًّا فَقالَ رَبِّ إِنِّی وَهَنَ
>   الْعَظْمُ مِنِّی وَ اشْتَعَلَ الرَّأْسُ شَیْباً وَ لَمْ أَکُنْ
>   بِدُعائِکَ رَبِّ شَقِیًّا وَ قُلْتَ یَدْعُونَنا رَغَباً وَ رَهَباً وَ
>   کانُوا لَنا خاشِعِینَ. وَ أَنْتَ الَّذِی اسْتَجَبْتَ لِلَّذِینَ
>   آمَنُوا وَ عَمِلُوا الصَّالِحَاتِ لِتَزِیدَهُمْ مِنْ فَضْلِکَ، فَلَا
>   تَجْعَلْنِی مِنْ أَهْوَنِ الدَّاعِینَ لَکَ وَ الرَّاغِبِینَ إِلَیْکَ،
>   وَ اسْتَجِبْ لِی کَمَا اسْتَجَبْتَ لَهُمْ بِحَقِّهِمْ عَلَیْکَ،
>   فَطَهِّرْنِی بِتَطْهِیرِکَ وَ تَقَبَّلْ صَلَاتِی وَ دُعَائِی بِقَبُولٍ
>   حَسَنٍ وَ طَیِّبْ بَقِیَّةَ حَیَاتِی وَ طَیِّبْ وَفَاتِی وَ اخْلُفْنِی
>   فِیمَنْ أَخْلُفُ، وَ احْفَظْنِی یَا رَبِّ بِدُعَائِی، وَ اجْعَلْ
>   ذُرِّیَّتِی ذُرِّیَّةً طَیِّبَةً تَحُوطُهَا بِحِیَاطَتِکَ بِکُلِّ مَا
>   حُطْتَ بِهِ ذُرِّیَّةَ أَحَدٍ مِنْ‏ أَوْلِیَائِکَ وَ أَهْلِ طَاعَتِکَ
>   بِرَحْمَتِکَ یَا أَرْحَمَ الرَّاحِمِینَ. یَا مَنْ هُوَ عَلَى کُلِّ
>   شَیْ‏ءٍ رَقِیبٌ، وَ لِکُلِّ دَاعٍ مِنْ خَلْقِکَ مُجِیبٌ، وَ مِنْ کُلِّ
>   سَائِلٍ قَرِیبٌ، أَسْأَلُکَ یَا لَا إِلَهَ إِلَّا أَنْتَ الْحَیُّ
>   الْقَیُّومُ، الْأَحَدُ الصَّمَدُ الَّذِی لَمْ یَلِدْ وَ لَمْ یُولَدْ
>   وَ لَمْ یَکُنْ لَهُ کُفُواً أَحَدٌ، وَ بِکُلِّ اسْمٍ رَفَعْتَ بِهِ
>   سَمَاءَکَ، وَ فَرَشْتَ بِهِ أَرْضَکَ، وَ أَرْسَیْتَ بِهِ الْجِبَالَ،
>   وَ أَجْرَیْتَ بِهِ الْمَاءَ، وَ سَخَّرْتَ بِهِ السَّحَابَ وَ الشَّمْسَ
>   وَ الْقَمَرَ وَ النُّجُومَ وَ اللَّیْلَ وَ النَّهَارَ، وَ خَلَقْتَ
>   الْخَلَائِقَ کُلَّهَا، أَسْأَلُکَ بِعَظَمَةِ وَجْهِکَ الْعَظِیمِ،
>   الَّذِی أَشْرَقَتْ لَهُ السَّمَاوَاتُ وَ الْأَرْضُ، فَأَضَاءَتْ بِهِ
>   الظُّلُمَاتُ، إِلَّا صَلَّیْتَ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَ آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ، وَ
>   کَفَیْتَنِی أَمْرَ مَعَاشِی وَ مَعَادِی، وَ أَصْلَحْتَ لِی شَأْنِی
>   کُلَّهُ، وَ لَمْ تَکِلْنِی إِلَى نَفْسِی طَرْفَةَ عَیْنٍ، وَ
>   أَصْلَحْتَ أَمْرِی وَ أَمْرَ عِیَالِی، وَ کَفَیْتَنِی هَمَّهُمْ، وَ
>   أَغْنَیْتَنِی وَ إِیَّاهُمْ مِنْ کَنْزِکَ وَ خَزَائِنِکَ، وَ سَعَةِ
>   فَضْلِکَ الَّذِی لَا یَنْفَدُ أَبَداً، وَ اثْبُتْ فِی قَلْبِی
>   یَنَابِیعَ الْحِکْمَةِ الَّتِی تَنْفَعُنِی بِهَا وَ تَنْفَعُ بِهَا
>   مَنِ ارْتَضَیْتَ مِنْ عِبَادِکَ، وَ اجْعَلْ لِی مِنَ الْمُتَّقِینَ فِی
>   آخِرِ الزَّمَانِ إِمَاماً کَمَا جَعَلْتَ إِبْرَاهِیمَ الْخَلِیلَ
>   إِمَاماً. فَإِنَّ بِتَوْفِیقِکَ یَفُوزُ الْفَائِزُونَ، وَ یَتُوبُ
>   التَّائِبُونَ، وَ یَعْبُدُکَ الْعَابِدُونَ، وَ بِتَسْدِیدِکَ یَصْلُحُ
>   الصَّالِحُونَ الْمُحْسِنُونَ الْمُخْبِتُونَ، الْعَابِدُونَ لَکَ،
>   الْخَائِفُونَ مِنْکَ، وَ بِإِرْشَادِکَ نَجَا النَّاجُونَ مِنْ نَارِکَ،
>   وَ أَشْفَقَ مِنْهَا الْمُشْفِقُونَ مِنْ خَلْقِکَ، وَ بِخِذْلَانِکَ
>   خَسِرَ الْمُبْطِلُونَ، وَ هَلَکَ الظَّالِمُونَ، وَ غَفَلَ
>   الْغَافِلُونَ. اللَّهُمَّ آتِ نَفْسِی تَقْوَاهَا، فَأَنْتَ وَلِیُّهَا
>   وَ مَوْلَاهَا، وَ أَنْتَ خَیْرُ مَنْ زَکَّاهَا، اللَّهُمَّ بَیِّنْ
>   لَهَا هُدَاهَا، وَ أَلْهِمْهَا تَقْوَاهَا، وَ بَشِّرْهَا بِرَحْمَتِکَ
>   حِینَ تَتَوَفَّاهَا، وَ نَزِّلْهَا مِنَ الْجِنَانِ عُلْیَاهَا، وَ
>   طَیِّبْ وَفَاتَهَا وَ مَحْیَاهَا، وَ أَکْرِمْ مُنْقَلَبَهَا وَ
>   مَثْوَاهَا، وَ مُسْتَقَرَّهَا وَ مَأْوَاهَا، فَأَنْتَ وَلِیُّهَا وَ
>   مَوْلَاهَا»

---

**Reference:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa48966)